# Bash Script Passes Variable that is a Hex Number to a Perl Regex Search to Match MAC Address

Tags: regex, bash, perl, hex, mac-address

I have be hitting my head against the wall trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. My code currently is this:

```
#!\bin\sh 

read -p "Enter Third Octet Here " octet
perl -ne 'while(/[0-9A-F]{2}[:-][0-9A-F]{2}[:-]("$ENV{'$octet'}")[:-][0-9A-F]{2}[:-][0-9A-F]{2}[:-][0-9A-F]{2}(?=((\s)|(\/)))/ig){print "$&\n";}' manuf.txt
perl -ne 'while(/[0-9A-F]{2}[:-][0-9A-F]{2}[:-]("$ENV{'$octet'}")(?=((\s)|(\/)))/ig){print "$&\n";}' manuf.txt
```

What I'm trying to do is identify the third octet of a MAC address against a manufacturer lookup list (https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf). I want the script to pass the variable 55,B3,b3,FF to the perl one-liner and have it insert it into the MAC regex and then print matches line by line. So far, without the variable, it will find every MAC address in the file whether it is denoted with a : or a - and whether it is a 6 octet string or a 3 octet string. with the env variable, it returns nothing. I've tried everything and nothing seems to work. I've hit a wall

I also want to be able to do a secondary match based on the 3rd and 4th octet and a tertiary match based on the 3rd and 4th and 5th octet as well, but that is a distant goal beyond just getting it to work

Answer (score 3):

To pass shell variable to a Perl one-liner, use `-s` option. For example:

```
SOME_VAR=test
perl -se 'print $var' -- -var=$SOME_VAR
```

Comment: that line works. It prints, for example c2 if I set the variable as c2 in bash. How would I integrate it into the line:

Comment: perl -ne 'while(/[0-9A-F]{2}[:-][0-9A-F]{2}[:-]("$ENV{'$octet'}")[:-][0-9A-F]{2}[:-][0-9A-F]{2}[:-][0-9A-F]{2}(?=((\s)|(\/)))/ig){print "$&\n";}' manuf.txt

Comment: besides changing the -ne to an se? I have changed the "-ne" to an "-se" and changed the $octet to $var and added "-- -var=$SOME_VAR" after the ' and before the "manuf.txt", but it does not work

Comment: You need both `-n` (to read the manuf.txt file) and `-s`. So the simplified one-liner would be: `perl -nse 'print if /$octet/' -- -octet=$octet manuf.txt`

Comment: so I change it to: perl -nse 'print if /[0-9A-F]{2}[:-][0-9A-F]{2}[:-]("$ENV{'$octet'}")[:-][0-9A-F]{2}[:-][0-9A-F]{2}[:-][0-9A-F]{2}(?=((\s)|(\/)))/ig' -- -octet=$octet manuf.txt

Comment: and it prints nothing when I enter c2 as the variable. I know there's a third octet in the file that says "c2"

Comment: Change `"$ENV{'$octet'}"` to `$octet`. `%ENV` is used for accessing environment variables from within Perl, which you don't need to do, as the variable is passed as `$octet`.

Comment: This is strange, for some reason when I use perl -nse 'print if /[0-9A-F]{2}[:-][0-9A-F]{2}[:-]$octet[:-][0-9A-F]{2}[:-][0-9A-F]{2}[:-][0-9A-F]{2}(?=((\s)|(\/)))/ig' -- -octet=$octet manuf.txt it only prints matches that have a ":" and ignore matches that have a "-"

Comment: much thanks for your help, it is matching the third octet with : and - after creating seperate sets of queries for the alternate notation

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it all in perl?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#get input
print "Enter third octet:\n";
chomp ( my $input = <> );

#open our file for reading. 
open ( my $manuf, '<', 'manuf.txt') or die $!;

#iterate line by line
while (<$manuf>) {
   #match instances of octets from the file, into $mac
   my ($mac) = m/((?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:-]?){3})/ or next;
   #split it on 'nonwords' which means pretty much any delimiter. 
   #map {lc} lowercases the elements, this makes the whole thing case
   #insensitive.  
   my @octets = map { lc } split /\W/, $mac;
   #print if there's a match
   print if $octets[2] eq lc $input; 
}

close ( $manuf );
```

IF you want to match multiple, then the easiest way is to probably reformat your input to be delimiter blind, and `regex` match it. Something like this:

```
$input =~ s/\W/:/g;
```

Will convert the input delimiters to `:` regardless of what someone gives. So you can enter:

```
00:00:0A
00-0A-00
00 0A-FF
```

Then, you can match in in the loop - rather than testing an octet match, use a regex match:

```
while (<$manuf>) {
   my ($mac) = m/^((?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:-]?){3})/ or next;
   my $reformatted_mac = join ":", map { lc } split /\W/, $mac;
   print if $reformatted_mac =~ m/$input/; 
}
```

Now, this is using regular expressions, so it's actually a substring match. It's also unanchored, so if you 'input' '0A' you'll match everything with an `0A` in the string.

But you could instead:

```
   print if $reformatted_mac =~ m/^$input/;
```

But then you'll always have to enter the 'starting' octets. (But it wouldn't be too hard to support regex input at that point too).

Comment: This script works exactly like I wanted, but in a stand alone. How would you change it so that I could enter "c2:00" or "c2:00:00" as input?

Comment: ah, ideally I would be grep'ing a result to input into the perl script when it runs. so I might get a result that is 00:50:C2:D5:60:22, I'd want to try C2:D5:60 first, then if no matches C2:D5, then if no matches C2 to try to get the smallest list possible. rn on the third octet, I'm getting 4000 matches, but if I do a search in my text editor for C2:D5:60 I get one result, C2:D5 16 results

Comment: I could just replace all the "-" in the manufacturer file with ":" then follow your suggestion to format the input into a ":" notation if I did that, how could I rewrite the script to take "C2:56:40" as my input variable, try "C2:56:40" followed by "C2:56" followed by "C2" ?

Comment: I'm going to take some time and play with this, post my results when I have something that works just like I want it. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My final code ended up being

```js
  #!\bin\sh 
#requires perl
#requires manuf.txt available from wireshark
#requires last 4 octets of mac address available from Ubertooth-scan
#use responsibly and don't use for any unauthorized purposes
#based in part on code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36119396/bash-script-passes-variable-that-is-a-hex-number-to-a-perl-regex-search-to-match?noredirect=1#comment59878958_36119396

read -p "Enter Third and Fourth and Fifth and Sixth Octet Here (AB:CD:EF:12) " STR

octet6=$(echo $STR | cut -c 1-11)
octet5=$(echo $STR | cut -c 1-8)
octet4=$(echo $STR | cut -c 1-5)
octet=$(echo $STR | cut -c 1-2)

#Makes sure the manuf.txt file only contains ":" notation
sed -i 's/-/:/ig' manuf.txt

#third and fourth and fifth octet
perl -nse 'print if /[0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:]$octet[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}(?=((\s)|(\/)))/ig' -- -octet=$octet5 manuf.txt

perl -nse 'print if /[0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:]$octet(?=((\s)|(\/)))/ig' -- -octet=$octet5 manuf.txt

#third and fourth octet
perl -nse 'print if /[0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:]$octet[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}(?=((\s)|(\/)))/ig' -- -octet=$octet4 manuf.txt

perl -nse 'print if /[0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:]$octet(?=((\s)|(\/)))/ig' -- -octet=$octet4 manuf.txt

#Third octet. Kind of pointless bc it might generate hundreds or thousands of matches
perl -nse 'print if /[0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:]$octet[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}(?=((\s)|(\/)))/ig' -- -octet=$octet manuf.txt

perl -nse 'print if /[0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:]$octet(?=((\s)|(\/)))/ig' -- -octet=$octet manuf.txt

#Trim things up and make them look neat and tidy
sed -i -E 's/^([0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}).*/\1/g' matches.txt
sed -i -E 's/^([0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2})\s.*/\1/ig' matches.txt

#Replace everything after the third octet with the rest of the Mac address for 6 octetc strings
sed -i -E 's/^([0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:])[0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}[:][0-9A-F]{2}/\1'$octet6'/g' matches.txt

#Replace everything after the third octet with the rest of the Mac address for 3 octetc strings
sed -i -E 's/^([0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}):[0-9A-F]{2}$/\1:'$octet6'/g' matches.txt

#Remove repeated strings
sed -i '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D' matches.txt
```

Not pretty, but it gets the job done and it creates a list of matches useful for a PoC code